# Cannot see my custom IME in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a very simple QR input method in Android. Far from being actually runnable in "production", I am trying to run my custom QR keyboard application on my Nexus 6 device, at least to see where it will crash.

However, after deploying the APK to the device I cannot choose my custom input.

Following is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.zighinetto.qrkey" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name=".services.QrInputService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permissions.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/ime" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And... ime.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method
    android:isDefault="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</input-method>
```

So far I have: 
 - Enabled `CAMERA` permission because I need to use the camera
 - Created the IME service and linked it to the `BIND_INPUT_METHOD` permission, so that only the system can bind to it
 - NOT declared the `BIND_INPUT_METHOD` as permission used by my application, because only the system needs that permission.

I expect the new QR input service to be visible in Android's "Language and input" screen, however I cannot see it.

What is wrong in my manifest?

Comment: Could you please also post your ime.xml file.

Comment: Posted. I also tried to add a mock subtype with `<subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />` but same result

Comment: All seems ok. Can you also post something from your QrInputService?

Comment: Another shot in the dark... have you checked that your apk installed successfully? Sometimes android studio reports success but apk is not installed and some error is displayed in the logs.

Comment: Code here https://github.com/djechelon/openqrkey/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/zighinetto/qrkey/services/QrInputService.java. I know **it is incomplete**